# how to use ctools Wizard (custom modal) to show my custom form?

Tags: 7, comments, chaos-tool-suite

I look at the ctools ajax demo. there I look at the form wzards. They are so nicely displayed in popup window. I want the similar functionality for my comment form.
So how can I use this functionality of [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) module to display the comment form like ctools Wizard (custom modal)?

I am using drupal 7.